Is IOUtils.closeQuietly() thread safe?
I am getting this exception while closing the stream.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.zip.DeflaterInputStream.close(DeflaterInputStream.java:133)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(IOUtils.java:303)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(IOUtils.java:246)

The code in DeflateInputStream is as below
    /**
     * Closes this input stream and its underlying input stream, discarding
     * any pending uncompressed data.
     *
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (in != null) {
        try {
            // Clean up
            if (usesDefaultDeflater) {
                def.end();
            }

            in.close();
        } finally {
            in = null;
        }
      }

Using synchronized might effect the performance is there any way to solve this ?

The title of this question seems very different from the body of the question. (I can see how they might be related, but they're definitely not the same question.) Can you edit?

It is this close method that isn’t thread-safe. But why are you closing from two threads?

I would be surprised if any of the InputStreams and OutputStreams that the JDK provides are thread-safe because IMHO for IO thread-safety at the lowest stream level doesn't make sense (even if they were thread safe, different threads reading/writing random amounts of bytes from/to an IO stream don't make sense, they need coordination at a higher level and that means synchronization also belongs to that higher level). The question is why you are trying to close a single IO stream from multiple threads.
